# testing redux thunk async actions give undefined instead of promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme, jestjs, redux-thunk

I have a function which creates actions

```
export function dispatchAction (type, payload) {
 return dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: type, payload: payload})
 }
}
```

I am writing test for it

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import * as actions from './actions
const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])
const store = mockStore({})

describe('dispatch action', () => {
 it('should return action based on type and payload', () => {
  const type = 'TEST'
  const payload = 'payload'
  return store.dispatch(actions.dispatchAction(type, payload)).then(() 
   => {
    expect(store.getActions())
     .toEqual({type, payload})
    })
   })
 })
```

but I am getting the error that `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Comment: what is `mockStore`. What that function return?

Comment: updated the new code

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition):

> Any return value from the inner function will be available as the
>   return value of dispatch itself.

You don't return anything in your `dispatchAction`, hence the error message. If you want a `Promise`, then you have to return a `Promise`.